# A question regarding the cartesian product and the set of functions and $n$-ary operations

Tags: set-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two non empty sets and $n$ be a natural number, $n \geq 2$. We say that a function $f$ is an $n$-ary opearation if $f \in B^{A^n}$(i.e. $f \colon A^n \to B$). For any natural number $n$, any $n$-ary operation can be written in terms of binary operations, namely functions $b \colon A^2 \to B$, so $f(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)=b(b(a_1, b(a_2, ...), a_n), \forall a_i \in A, 1 \leq i \leq n$. I thought of proving this by induction, but I need the following lemma. 
> **Lemma:** Let $A$ and $I$ be two non empty finite(I think the argument here can be easily generalised for countable as well) sets. Then there is a bijection between $A^I$(i.e. all the functions $f \colon I \to A$) and $\mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A$ (here $\mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}$ represents the cartesian product). 
> *Proof*: Let $f \colon A^I \to \mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A$ defined as follows: If $g \in A^I$ then $f(g)=(g(a_1), g(a_2), ..., g(a_m))$, where $m = \lvert I \rvert$. If $f(g)=(a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, ..., a_{i_m})$ and $f(g)=(a_{j_1}, a_{j_2}, ..., a_{j_m})$ it follows that $g(a_1)=a_{i_1}=a_{j_1}, g(a_2)=a_{i_2}=a_{j_2}, ..., g(a_m)=a_{i_m}=a_{j_m}, \forall 1 \leq k \leq n, a_{i_k} \in A, b_{i_k} \in A$. This happens because $g$ is a function, therefore $f$ is well-defined.
> Now we porve $f$ is injective: Let $g$ and $h$ be two elements in $A^I$ such that $f(g)=f(h)$. This implies $(g(a_1), g(a_2), ..., g(a_m))=(h(a_1), h(a_2), ..., h(a_m)) \implies g(a_i)=h(a_i), \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$. Since $g$ and $h$ have the same domain and range, we have just proved $g=h$, which means $f$ is injective. 
> Now for the surjectivity: Let $(a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, ..., a_{i_m}) \in \mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A$. Then there exists a function $g \in A^I, g(i)=a_{i_k}$, so $f$ is surjective. 
> Therefore, $f$ is bijective(this could be deduced from the fact that they have the same cardinality, but I decided to also use this brute force approach, because I think it can be generalised for non-finite sets). **Q.E.D**
> Now let's solve the initial problem. 
> *Proof:*For the base case of the induction, $n=2$, any function $f \in B^{A^2}$ can be written (obviously) in terms of binary functions. We can take $g \in B^{A^2}$ such that $f=g$. Assume that for some $n$ any function $g \in B^{A^n}$ can be written in terms of binary functions. Now take $f \in B^{A^{n+1}}$; $A^{n+1}=A^n \times A \implies B^{A^{n+1}}=B^{A^{n} \times A}$. However $B^{A^{n} \times A}$ is the set of (binary)functions that takes in as a parameter a function from $B^{A^n}$ and another one from $A$. But since any element from $B^{A^n}$ can be written in terms of binary functions, we solved the problem. **Q.E.D.**

This is a proof I came up with, but I have several questions about it. The first one is whether or not it is valid for an infinite $n$(i.e. any $n$-ary function with $n$ infinite can be written in terms of binary functions, whatever that would mean). In general the cartesian product is not associative, namely $(A \times B) \times C \neq A \times (B \times C)$. If $((a, b), c) = (a, (b, c))$ $\implies (a, b)=a \text{ and } c=(b, c)$, which is not necessarily true. Can get along this problem using a bijection? If $A$ is a non-empty set and $I$ is finite, then one can find a bijection from $\mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A_i \times A$ to $A \times \mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A_i$. I would still use induction here, but my argument fails when $I$ is uncountable. The second question is "how much" set theory should I know? I have recently started studying it from online resources, but most of them are very "hard to digest" and use important results from logic and K.Gödel's work. Can anyone recommend some beginner friendly resources on theese subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then there is a bijection between $A^I$(i.e. all the functions $f \colon I \to A$) and $\mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}_{i \in I}A$ (here $\mathop{\Large\times\normalsize}$ represents the cartesian product).

These sets are by definition equal to each other, for any $A$ and $I$, finite or infinite.

It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'written in terms of binary operations'. If you mean that, for example, a 3-ary operation could be expressed as a binary operation from $A\times$the set of 2-ary operations to $B$, then this is correct, and it's called 'currying'. If you have a function $f$ in 2 variables, you can define $g(x)$ as being the functions that sends $y$ to $f(x,y)$. In this way you can decompose finite arity functions into binary functions. However it involves functions mapping functions to other functions, so can be confusing.

However, the way you've written it seems not to be correct. I will assume you meant the $b$s to be different functions $f(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)=b_1(b_2(a_1, b_3(a_2, ...), a_n)$, but if you mean these to be functions $A \times A \to B$, this is incorrect. Firstly, you're inputting the wrong kind of object into the functions; the output of $b_2$ is in $B$, but $b_1$ needs an input in $A$. But if we assume $A=B$ this still doesn't work:

Take $A=B=\{0,1\}$ and the 3-ary operation $f(x,y,z)=1$ iff $x=z$ and $y=1$

Then if we try to write $f(x,y,z)=g(h(x,y),z)$ there are no binary $g$ and $h$ from $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \to \{0,1\}$ which work. It must be that either $g(0,1)=1$ or $g(1,1)=1$, so suppose wlog that $g(1,1)=1$. Then it must be that $g(0,1)=0$, otherwise the output would be $1$ whenever $z=1$. But then $f(x,y,z)=1$ iff $x=z$ and $y=1$ requires $h(x,y)=1$ iff $x=1$ and $y=1$, by substituting $z=1$.

But then $f(0,1,0)=g(0,0)$ and $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0)$, even though $f(0,1,0)=1$ and $f(0,0,0)=0$. So by contradiction $f$ cannot be described in this way.